# Do p2 resperatiors provied any protection against asbestos? will I be ok?

Tags: asbestos, building

do n95 resperaitor filters provied any protection against asbestos. I am a 16 year old building apprentice and I am freaking out about this. I was working with my boss when he said that we would be cutting a soffit that may have asbestos. I had no idea how dangerous asbestos was so I agreed to do it. we were outside cutting a soffit for around 20 minutes with a duel filter 3m 3000 half face mask on. I also had a coverall on. my job was to try suck up as much Dust as I could with a makita shop vac. I managed to suck up around 50 to 60 percent of the dust. I find that some people say that they can filter some of the asbestos while others say they can not. I have severe anxiety which is most likly playing a big part in my worrys.

Comment: Similar question - https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/171238/do-n95-masks-provide-any-protection-against-asbestos

Comment: you say you were outside

Comment: Check with the local authorities… was this meeting the standards (if any) or just a cheapskate job?

Comment: What kind of filters did you put on the 3M face mask? PS: if there was asbestos, precautions will have to be taken when emptying the shop vac too.

Comment: https://www.bunnings.co.nz/3m-performance-reusable-paint-project-respirator_p0216042?store=9531 It was this exact mask

Comment: Yes I was outside

Comment: my boss empty the shop vac. I think he just dug a hole and buried it I was not there.

Comment: just did a bit more research it was a p2 resperatior with a 95% protection against particles

Comment: Most masks will provide some protection for asbestos.  Asbestos is dangerous if you are breathing in the fibres everyday.  I would be more concerned about your boss, since most places have quite a few tough regulations on how to handle asbestos, which your boss seems not to care about.  You might even be required to report him to health and labour departments.  Start looking for a new job.

Comment: I could never report my boss he gave me a opportunity of being a builder which I am very Thankful for. I think he is just one of the old guys who needs to get with the times a bit. Cheers though for calming my nerves a bit.

Comment: That is a decent mask. For the future, try to get p100 filters (round and pink here; probably the same there). You didn’t need the OV, though it didn’t hurt.

Comment: Keep educating yourself about jobsite hazards — there’s plenty you can do to protect yourself without confronting your boss.

Comment: also *don't panic*: asbestos doesn't just instantly kill people, it's not like toxic gas. IIRC people who were regularly exposed to asbestos had a higher risk of cancer, or something like that. The more asbestos, the more cancer. There were people working in asbestos factories 8 hours a day. So breathing it in one time accidentally (and you don't even know if it was actually there) isn't good for you, but you're not going to just drop dead.

Comment: You say you had a coverall on?  was it just a typical cloth coverall, or a disposable one?  Here is the USA, if there is any chance of encountering asbestos, a sample is taken and tested. If asbestos is found, that triggers full containment, ventilation, hazmat clothing, special procedures.  I think it's WAY overkill as long a reasonable precautions are taken.  I'll also reinforce what others have said here, even if you were exposed, it's not a poison, it's a naturally occurring mineral.  The people working around it all day every day are the ones at risk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I am freaking out about this

Because you're not an oncologist.

If you were, you'd wear a dust mask for comfort and not worry about it LOL.

Everybody treats asbestos like it's cyanide or something. But in order to actually have a health problem from asbestos, you have to work around airborne asbestos fibers *occupationally*, 8 hours a day, 2000 hours a year, for decades.

So why is everyone kicking up a fuss about asbestos? Because asbestos manufacturers set up *trust funds* to help asbestos workers who did have problems. Tapping the trust funds is a matter of assembling some documents and filling out some forms.  A little too complex to DIY, which has created a feeding frenzy of lawyers offering to help you gather papers *for a 1/3 contingency fee of the claim!*  And even more bottom-suckers who aren't even lawyers at all, but simply sell leads to law firms.  **This has created a tsunami of negative advertisements** which has created a state of panic.  And that's why you're freaking out.

But even if you had been wearing no PPE at all, your risk was essentially zero.  Even most people who worked a career around asbestos dust *don't* have problems.

Your risk of being susceptible to being manipulated by advertising is another matter entirely... but that's not your question.

Comment: thanks for calming my nerves

Answer (score 2):

It's not rated or approved.  See, e.g.  [this site](https://www.dir.ca.gov/dosh/dosh_publications/N95-mask-questions.html)  .
But since you don't even know if the workspace had asbestos, and your exposure time was tiny, the risk is small.  It's like the difference between one cigarette a week and 3 packs a day.

Comment: Per Carl the N95 is not approved for use with Asbestos, however your question was "Any"; so yes certainly some protection (actually if fitted, pretty good at filtering the larger asbestos fibers).  Have your boss get you a proper N100 full face filter mask for future potential  asbestos work. Also,  change the filters often.

Comment: I have a proper p100 now cheers mate